# psql asks for password, CREATE USER didn't specify one

Tags: postgresql, psql

I used to have a user, say 'jack' in postgresql, and then I forgot what the password. I reassigned all its ownerships to user postgres, removed the user, and then created it again with `CREATE USER jack;`.

Now if I try to connect with it, psql asks for a password.

```
$ psql db_name jack
Password for user jack: 
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

What is going on and how do I check if a user has a password or not?

Answer (score 4):

A user having a password or not won't affect if you're asked for a password when trying to connect.  That is controlled by [the `pg_hba.conf` file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

If you're being asked for a password that indicates that a password is required.  If you try to connect to an account which doesn't have a password set that will simply fail.  You need to either set a password for the account and use that, use a different type of connection or modify the `pg_hba.conf` file to use a different authentication method.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep a password on the account, and then use a local [password file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html) to skip having to enter the password each time.

> The file .pgpass in a user's home directory or the file referenced by
>   PGPASSFILE can contain passwords to be used if the connection requires
>   a password (and no password has been specified otherwise). On
>   Microsoft Windows the file is named %APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf
>   (where %APPDATA% refers to the Application Data subdirectory in the
>   user's profile).
>
> This file should contain lines of the following format:
>
> hostname:port:database:username:password

Answer (score -2):

If you want to have postgres never ask for a password for a specific user, then supply the `-w` option during user creation.

`createuser -w user`

(note that -W (capital w) will always prompt for a password)

By default users made in postgresql with `CREATE USER user` don't have a password.

[http://www.postgresql.org/.../app-createuser.html](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/app-createuser.html)

Comment: But I don't want a password, and I don't want psql to ask for one either.

Comment: I updated my answer, it wasn't clear you wanted it to not check for password.

Comment: You misunderstood the purpose of `-w` and `-W`. They're meant to give connection parameters to the `createuser` program itself, not to indicate how the future user may connect.